# Selenium WebDriver - Assert Fading message

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The scenario is that after I fill out all the necessary information (assume that they are all valid) of a form then select Save, I receive a message pops up for about 6-7 seconds saying that the form was saved successfully then it would fade away, along with its HTML code,which is

```
   <div data-notify="container" class="alert-success animated" role="alert" data-notify-position="top-right">
           <span data-notify="title">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">
              ::before
             </span>
             <span> Saving</span>
             <span data-modify="message">Successfully saved</span>
          </span>
</div>
```

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l6BZ.png)

I am trying to assert using the text "Successfully saved", with the following code:

```
String message = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.glyphicon glyphicon-ok")).getText();
assertTrue(message.contains("Successfully saved"));
```

Unfortunately, it returns with failure because the element could not be located

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"span.glyphicon glyphicon-ok"}
```

I am wondering whether it is my code was incorrect or the message fades away faster than the driver could locate the element.

Any help or correction would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Danny

Comment: part of the problem here may be that your cssSelector should not have a space in it.  I suggest just "span.glyphicon-ok" would be sufficient.  As a few others have mentioned, you also need to use a WebDriverWait.

Comment: Why not simplify things ?  Just Get the Page source and Verify if your message is present ?   like , driver.getPageSource().contains("Successfully saved");

Comment: Hi Arpan, I did indeed tried getPageSource at the very beginning but it didn't work, that's why I came here and asked for assistance. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys for being patient and attempting to help. I just managed to solve the issue with the following code. This is based on Efx's code but I tweaked it a little bit.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'col-xs-11 col-sm-4 alert alert-success animated fadeInDown fadeOutUp')]")));   
assertTrue(el.getText().contains("Successfully saved"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@data-notify='container']/descendant::span[@data-modify='message']")));
String message = el.getText();
assertTrue(message.contains("Successfully saved"));
```

Hope it will help you..:)

Comment: Hi Saurabh, thank you for the example, unfortunately it didn't work :-(, still unable to locate the element

Comment: `$x("//div[@data-notify='container']/descendant::span[@data-modify='message']")` copy this line and paste in browser console and let me know what are you getting???

Comment: Hi Saurabh, I just did on Chrome and the console returns nothing but blank []

Comment: As you say this element popup only for 6-7 second....so did you try at console when it was visible?

Comment: Hi Saurabh, yes I did, multiple times actually, but kept getting [] response

Comment: just do this at browser console `document.getElementsByTagName("frame")` and `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")` ....and let me know it's return empty array or not...

Comment: Hi Saurabh, I just gave it a try and the console returns an empty array as well. I am quite certain that the element is not in a frame or sort.

Comment: Could you please provide the website url that I could give you a better solution...

Comment: Hi Saurabh, I am not allowed to give the URL but I had edited my question with an image of the code that I inspected of the message. Hopefully that would do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i do it for modals. This should be placed after an event that triggers the modal.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.alert-success")));   
WebElement message = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@data-modify='message']"));
Assert.assertEquals("Successfully saved", message.getText());
```

Comment: Hi Efx, thank you for the example, unfortunately it didn't work :-(, still unable to locate the element. I had updated the post with an image of the full code, you can check it out.

Comment: Great! Right! waiting for the exact class value to be available.

Answer (score 1):

i assume that indentation of ur html code is as like as u given. So, try the below code:

```
//wait here for some momnent
String message = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.alert-success.animated>span>span:nth-child(3)")).getText();
printn("message is " +message);
assertTrue(message.contains("Successfully saved"));
```

let me know what happens.

Comment: Hi noor, thank you for the example, unfortunately it didn't work :-(, still unable to locate the element. I had updated the post with an image of the full code, you can check it out.

Comment: Yes that because ur given html is not same with the image....u can not expect correct ans from a wrong html